# How create a card in MaterialApp using flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(
  MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter demo page'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'abcd',
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 30.0),
            ),
            Text('\n'
                'abcd',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you create it using a `Card` widget like this

```
Card(
          elevation: 20,
          child: FlutterLogo(size: 200),
        )
```

please next time do more research before posting a question, because you have could got the answer simply by searching **Flutter Card**.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a [Card Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Card-class.html) or a [Material Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Material-class.html). Their usage are pretty simple and you can find it in the docs.

The only difference between them is that card is a pre-configured and more limited Material. But still pretty good and preferred most of the time.

Just a tip, whenever you'll post some on StackOverflow use [code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). It makes a lot easier to understand your problem.